# Unidentified control sequence error in equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors

I have a problem to a question that I don't find the answer to.
I wanted to represent a system of equations but it gives me the following error "unidentified control sequence". Additionally in one equation my lamdas missing in the output.
These are my equations in Latex code:

`$\frac{\partial W}{\partial x} = 0,1 - 2 \lamda \sigma_x^2 x - 2\lamda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}y - \mu = 0$`

`$\frac{\partial W}{\partial y} = 0,5 - 2 \lamda \sigma_y^2 y - 2\lamda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}x - \mu = 0$`

`$\frac{\partial W}{\partial p} = - 2p\mu = 0$`

`$\frac{\partial W}{\partial \lamda } = -\lamda_x^2x^2-\lamda_y^2y^2-2\lamda_x\lamda_y\rho_{xy}+\lamda_p^2 = 0$`

`$\frac{\partial W}{\partial \mu} = -x-y-p^2+1 = 0$`

In the following you can see my output. I get the error message for all lines. Additionally, as you can see in equation 4 the lamdas are missing from the output.
I hope someone can help me on this issue
[image: latex output]

Comment: Welcome in TeX.SE. community. I think that the problem is "\lamda". The correct greek letter is \lambda. In addition, can you put a complete example starting from \documentclass to \end{document}, please?

Comment: It is probably exactly only @Sebastiano suggested: When the correct control sequence `\lambda` is used (instead of `\lamda`, which LaTeX cannot know) my guess is the "unknown control sequence" will disappear.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Thank you very much for your approvation. :-)

Comment: Note that the error message (which you did not show) does show you _which_ command is undefined, so it will hav epointed to `\lamda` here.

Comment: Not the stated subject of the question, but you will notice that the lines of the example are bashing into one another.  That is because the math is treated "in-line".  What you really need (and is addressed in the answer) is to treat them as a multi-line display.  There are many possibilities, most provided by the `amsmath` package.  You would benefit from reading the documentation: In your browser, go to https://texdoc.org and enter `amsldoc`; there are several language-specific options; choose the one that's most suitable.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

From my comment...here there is the solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial x} &= 0,1 - 2 \lambda \sigma_x^2 x - 2\lambda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}y - \mu = 0\\ 
\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}& = 0,5 - 2 \lambda \sigma_y^2 y - 2\lambda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}x - \mu = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial p}& = - 2p\mu = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \lambda}&= -\lambda_x^2x^2-\lambda_y^2y^2-2\lambda_x\lambda_y\rho_{xy}+\lambda_p^2 = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \mu}& = -x-y-p^2+1 = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

### Addendum 1:

If you use the `siunitx` package with the option

```
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
```

you will have not a lot of space between the comma and the **1** or **5**. See this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial x} &= \num{0,1} - 2 \lambda \sigma_x^2 x - 2\lambda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}y - \mu = 0\\ 
\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}& = \num{0,5} - 2 \lambda \sigma_y^2 y - 2\lambda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}x - \mu = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial p}& = - 2p\mu = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \lambda}&= -\lambda_x^2x^2-\lambda_y^2y^2-2\lambda_x\lambda_y\rho_{xy}+\lambda_p^2 = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \mu}& = -x-y-p^2+1 = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addendum 2:

Here using the suggestion of very nice user @Mico with the `icomma` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial x} &= 0,1 - 2 \lambda \sigma_x^2 x - 2\lambda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}y - \mu = 0\\ 
\frac{\partial W}{\partial y}& = 0,5 - 2 \lambda \sigma_y^2 y - 2\lambda\sigma_x\sigma_y\rho_{xy}x - \mu = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial p}& = - 2p\mu = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \lambda}&= -\lambda_x^2x^2-\lambda_y^2y^2-2\lambda_x\lambda_y\rho_{xy}+\lambda_p^2 = 0\\
\frac{\partial W}{\partial \mu}& = -x-y-p^2+1 = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Nice touch to employ a `split` environment. Another way to inform LaTeX that it should treat instances of `,` in math mode as the decimal separator is to load the `icomma` package. That way, it's not necessary to encase `0,1` and `0,5` in `\num` directives.

Comment: Hi very kindest :-) thank you lot lot for this package that I not know :-))))...